# IOS HTML5 - UI slider

Tags: jquery, ios, css, html

Can anyone recommend a simple jquery UI slider that I could use in a HTML5 IOS app?

I need to display a slider within an overlay that I can receive percentage data from when submitted.

Cheers

Comment: If this is for an HTML5 iOS app, why not just use <input type="range">? Not need for a custom jQuery control...

Comment: spot on cheers for your help

Comment: if you mark it as an answer I'll give you a tick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for an HTML5 iOS app (webkit), you can use:

```
<input type="range">
```

Answer (score 2):

try the [jQuery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/). The page contains examples which could be adapted to display a percentage